# Perform operation on subset of vector in rust?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, quicksort

I'm very new to Rust, and I come from C++ land. I'm trying to use the experimental `Vec::partition_at_index` function.  I'm trying to call this function on a certain range of indices of my vector, but have it still modify the original vector (I'm implementing a version of quicksort). Is there a way this can be done?

I also noticed `Iterator::partition_in_place`. Is this more what I should going for? Can the iterator version be used to operate on a subset of values?

If there are C++ folks hanging out here, I'm looking for the behavior of `std::partition`, which can operate on an iterator range.

Comment: The method `partition_at_index` is implemented for **slices**, so you can write `vec[2..5].partition_at_index(...)`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware taking a slice with `operator[]` was a thing.